# In TensorFlow is min_score_thresh related to IoU?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am currently investigating object detection using TensorFlow. The minimum score threshold during object detection can be changed and I would like to know if this value is related to the IoU value as it has defaulted to 0.5 (the traditional value used for IoU).

Answer (score 0):

They are different. `IoU` basically means Intersection over Union. Setting a value of 0.5 (which is usually the default value in most cases) means that the model will only consider those detections that have an IoU of **at least** 0.5 with the ground-truth box (applied during training and validation).

Detection score or the min score threshold is the confidence with which the model predicts a particular box having an object belonging to a certain class. This is mainly used as a filter during test time to keep only those detections having scores greater than a threshold (0.5 is a good choice for most cases)